# Backtracing linux socket with gdb - functions not being shown, buffer not updating

Tags: c, linux, sockets, debugging, gdb

As mentioned in the title, gdb behaves weirdly when I try to set a breakpoint at linux socket functions such as send etc. I've read through similar threads where it's been suggested to use the debug argument, but I can't set it as I'm just messing around with different Linux programs/video games and I've noticed the same behaviour - for the most part, send can't be backtraced. Only the familiar "< memory address > in ??" messages are shown, and the addresses themselves don't point to anything (can't be retrieved). At the same time, the message buffer in send (or sendto etc) is stuck at one value and not updating (while all the other values such as len are, in real time). I suppose these are simply limitations of gdb, but I'd appreciate it if someone more knowledgeable could shed some light on the issue.

EDIT:

First I'll list my steps:
As an example, I'm trying to backtrace the *sendto* in openarena (free linux quake-based game). Openarena in particular is not ELF readable, but I get the same results with other ELF-readable files. Because it isn't ELF-readable, I can only attach to a running process. So I type *gdb /usr/games/openarena -p < process name >* , though I'm pretty sure the binary path is redundant in this case
(it still says *"0x7ffc8a81ebe0s": not in executable format: file format not recognized*, but I'm able to list functions and everything anyway) As a side note, attaching produces this bug:

((( https://forum.manjaro.org/t/critical-bug-gdb-broken-with-last-stable-update/53155

*"Error while reading shared library symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0:"*

However, in my case, I'm still able to attach, but the program eventually crashes after complaining about not being able to find a thread. This also often happens when joining a server from a lobby, but this is a side note, as I've tested programs by running them directly from gdb as well which doesn't produce the error, but still led to this weird socket behaviour. )))

So after attaching to the process, I type *source script*, the script containing:

```
break sendto
commands 1
backtrace -raw-frame-arguments on 
continue
end
```

I then resume the program and it's firing backtraces in realtime. This is sample output after joining a server:

```
Thread 1 "ioquake3" hit Breakpoint 1, __libc_sendto (fd=43, buf=0x7ffefc5028f0, len=32, flags=0, addr=..., addrlen=16) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sendto.c:25
25      in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sendto.c
#0  __libc_sendto (fd=43, buf=0x7ffefc5028f0, len=32, flags=0, addr=..., addrlen=16) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sendto.c:25
#1  0x00005642f88bc5fc in ?? ()
#2  0x00005642f88baf94 in ?? ()
#3  0x00005642f888b1ee in ?? ()
#4  0x00005642f88779cf in ?? ()
#5  0x00005642f8886572 in ?? ()
#6  0x00005642f88a58bf in ?? ()
#7  0x00005642f886e3f5 in main ()

Thread 1 "ioquake3" hit Breakpoint 1, __libc_sendto (fd=43, buf=0x7ffefc5028f0, len=34, flags=0, addr=..., addrlen=16) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sendto.c:25
25      in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sendto.c
#0  __libc_sendto (fd=43, buf=0x7ffefc5028f0, len=34, flags=0, addr=..., addrlen=16) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sendto.c:25
#1  0x00005642f88bc5fc in ?? ()
#2  0x00005642f88baf94 in ?? ()
#3  0x00005642f888b1ee in ?? ()
#4  0x00005642f88779cf in ?? ()
#5  0x00005642f8886572 in ?? ()
#6  0x00005642f88a58bf in ?? ()
#7  0x00005642f886e3f5 in main ()
```

As you can see, there is nothing between main and the send, the socket buffer is stuck at the same message, while len is updating correctly. I can perform any kind of actions, jump, shoot, and the output still stays the same. As I mentioned, I get pretty much the same output with other applications. There's some main function/loop, then nothing and then just the send function.

As for my system specs, I'm on Kubuntu 21.04,
GDB version is: GNU gdb (Ubuntu 10.1-2ubuntu2) 10.1.90.20210411-git
Glibc: Ubuntu GLIBC 2.33-0ubuntu5

I've migrated recently from an earlier LTS release, the upgrade might not have been entirely clean, I suppose...

Comment: This question needs a lot more data: exact output from GDB, versions of GDB and GLIBC in use, actual commands and GDB responses, etc.

Comment: Okay, I'll post a detailed edit shortly!

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: I don't know why I'm getting downvoted, by the way. I'm not trying to cheat in openarena, if that's what you're thinking. I'd be the last person to do so (and it would be a pretty ridiculous thing to attempt). This is just an example.

Comment: Are use sure the binary has a debug info `gdb` can understand, something like DWARF?

Comment: I've been looking at various programs, I don't know what debug info they have. I'm quite new to gdb. However, I can easily view functions, variables etc.

Comment: What other programs have to do with the problem? I'm asking about about the program you are trying to debug. Debug info isn't something specific to `gdb`, all debuggers use debug info from binary, if it is there

Comment: As I've mentioned, I've been trying to debug a variety of programs. But in this particular case, I can for instance see certain functions (that should be there) don't show up in the functions list, but others do.

Comment: "I don't know why I'm getting downvoted" -- because your question lacked _all_ relevant details. I've retracted my downvote.

Comment: @swaggg You are just confusing people by adding irrelevant information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see, there is nothing between main and the send, the socket buffer is stuck at the same message, while len is updating correctly.

A few points:

1. There are no *function names* (which isn't the same as "nothing"). That is expected IF there is no symbol table. GDB uses symbol table(s) from loaded binaries to translate addresses into function names.
   If the binary is fully stripped, or if the code generated into memory directly, or if the binary is decompressed or decrypted into memory, then you would need to teach GDB where it can get the symbol table from (if the symbol table exists *at all*, which isn't a given).
2. The socket buffer being "stuck" is not necessarily unexpected either: the program is very likely to be doing *repeated* `sendto` calls using the *same* stack buffer. Like this:

```
  while (!error) {
    char buf[4096];
    int n = copy_to(buf);  // fill buf[] with data
    if (sendto(fd, buf, n, ...) != n) // handle error  
  }
```

**Update:**

> I still don't quite understand why I can't see buffer values change.

You are not looking at the buffer *contents*, you are looking at the buffer *address* (i.e. `&buf[0]` given the code above).

If you want to look at the buffer contents, you need to print / examine it. E.g. to examine the first 8 bytes being sent, add this to your breakpoint command: `x/8cx buf`. But also note that it is common to have a fixed prefix on all the packets being sent, and it's not guaranteed that the 8 leading bytes will change on every packet either.

Comment: Thanks! That's some really useful information. I don't think it's fully stripped (if that's possible). Certain functions I can find in the source code are still accessible, but others aren't. I still don't quite understand why I can't see buffer values change. Shouldn't they be displayed starting from the most important (first) byte in big-endian?

Comment: It seems UI functions have been kept, but game logic and state functions aren't accessible.